# Machine Independency

Tags: operating-system, hardware, cpu-architecture

Let's think about a simple C program compiled in Windows.

I can compile the program on an Intel CPU machine and run it on an AMD CPU one (same operating system). So does it mean that the instruction set of the CPU's are the same?

Why doesn't the same program run on a machine with different OS and the same CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary setup of the object files are totally different. Also which libraries are available or how to call them.

Just compare the header of an ELF or an EXE file to see what I mean.

If you write a simple program like "main(){printf("Hello\n"); return 0;} there is a lot going on behind the scenes that are covered by the compiler to get these lines printed. Running on the same CPU doesn't help, because it could execute the assembly instructions, but it would fail horribly as soon as calling the first OS function.

To elaborate this a bit:

Just as an exmaple. Lets assume that we are running on Amiga OS with a Motorola 68000 CPU.

If I remember correctly, the calling convetions to call a system library involved loading the pointers into i.e. an adress register of the CPU and then call the OS function.

Now lets assume I write my own OS also using a Motorola 68000 CPU. However, when I design my OS, I thought it is a much better idea to use the stack for data exchange, so when you call a similar function in my own private OS, you don't pass the adress in the address register, instead you push it on the stack.
Now when your executable would be executed in my OS (supposing it could be loaded because I use the same object structure) your executable would put values in a register and my OS would try to pop them from the stack, because it doesn't know that the values it was looking for were supposed to be somehwere else.

I hope this is a bit more detailed so you can understand it, but of course the problems go much deeper then this, as this is just a tiny part of the problems involved.

Comment: Edited the text with an example to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: oh nice illustration..hey do you know any good book to know how computer works right from the machine level(digital logic)?

Comment: I'd like to add that the reason for this is that operating systems try their best to provide abstraction from hardware. Particularly for convenience, portability and security reasons.

Comment: Sorry, I can't recommend one from the top of my head. I would look for "von Neumann architecture" to get you started, or books about operating system design. This question is rather broad so a recommendation might also depend on your intended architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Both your Intel and AMD use the x86 (or x86-64) architecture. That's why you can run the same software on both. However, the compiled program contains more than just dependencies on the architecture, it also contains dependencies on the underlying operating system. Even the binary format of a Linux executable for example is different from a Windows one.

You can however take a simple C program which uses the C standard library and compile it across different operating systems and processor architectures. As long as your code does not contain operating system dependent code, it will port across operating systems. Similarly, if your code does not rely on the underlying architecture endianess for instance, it will port across architectures.

Johan.

Comment: Thanks. how porting is acheived at run time?

Comment: What do you mean "at runtime"? If you mean by that that compatibillity is achieved at runtime (wine on Linux is a good example) it means that somebody wrote a wrapper which knows how to load executables and then intercepts the calls from the binary and translating it into the underlying OS. Otherweise it's not possible to port an executable at runtime. You always need an emulation layer.

Comment: @ShankarNShankar port at runtime can only be pulled off if the OS has a large body of code that is able to read and execute a **foreign** executable. These days that is a **Virtual Machine** (VM). I can be pulled off without a VM on some platforms where the two platforms are similar enough that a full VM is not required. **Wine** which runs Windows x86 on Linux x86 or Mac x86 is one example.

Comment: @ShankarNShankar The runtime (e.g., C runtime) is implemented on a per-platform basis. Let's assume we have two micro controllers, one a Renesas M16C one and an ARM (LPC2138) one. Both will need the C runtime ported to their specific requirements before any C code can be compiled for the micro controller in question.